# IE6 Ajax with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, internet-explorer

I'm trying to fecth data from a REST webservice into a HTML page. The problem is Internet Explorer 6 (which is my target station on XP SP3) that I'm struggling to make work.
Here's the code used :

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType : 'json',
       url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
       success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
       },
       complete: function(xhr) {
          alert(xhr.status+" "+xhr.responseText);
       }
});
```

Tested on Firefox 52 ESR : both success and complete functions works.

On Chrome 49 : success works, complete is called but xhr.status is 0 and xhr.responseText is empty.

On IE6 success is not called at all and complete is called but xhr.status is 0 and xhr.responseText is undefined.

Tried what was already answered here on SOF like removing extra commas, adding dataType ... but still no success with IE6.

How can we do it once for all ?

Thanks

Comment: `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",` is nonsense, you are making a GET request, there is no request body to describe the type of.

Comment: Windows XP reached end-of-life half a decade ago and has not had a security patch since then. Do not use it. Upgrade the target station.

Comment: That's not for me. Client has XP deployed over thousands of stations and is looking for solutions with lesser changes . I agree about everything you said but I can't do much about it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Quentin said, sending CORS request is not supported in IE 6/7, you could check [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/sending-a-cors-request-in-ie/).

You could refer to the following code to [use JSONP](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/).

```
// Using JSONP
$.ajax({
    url: "<request url>",
    jsonp: "callback",

    // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        q: "select title,abstract,url from search.news where query=\"cat\"",
        format: "json"
    },

    // Work with the response
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

Besides, please check [this article](https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests):

*Internet Explorer 9 and earlier ignores Access-Control-Allow headers and by default prohibits cross-origin requests for Internet Zone. To enable cross-origin access go to Tools->Internet Options->Security tab, click on “Custom Level” button. Find the Miscellaneous -> Access data sources across domains setting and select “Enable” option.*

Comment: Tried this method with mocky.io jsonp service and it's seems to work with IE6. Now I'll have to make my webservice jsonp compatible

Comment: @Quentin,  Thanks for reminding me about that. it is just a same code, when we use it, we could change to our request url. I have modified the reply. Thanks again.

Comment: You can't use an **arbitrary** request URL with this code, it needs to specifically be an implementation of Yahoo!'s no-longer-supported YQL API.

Comment: @Quentin, OK, got it. Thanks for reminding me about that.

Answer (score 3):

IE6 is **ancient**, it does not support CORS (not even with `XDomainRequest`).

There is no way to perform cross-origin RESTful HTTP requests with JavaScript in IE6.

If you want to perform a cross-origin request, then you will need to use some other (non-RESTful) approach such as JSONP.